# How to fine tune the last layers of neural network in target model for transfer learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am learning how transfer learning works using this data https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santander-customer-satisfaction/data .. so this is my **simple source model code** in tensorflow. and I am saving this model

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
import numpy  as np
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
""" # Read in the csv data using pandas 
train  = pd.read_csv('Z:\ADwork2\python\PM/train.csv',index_col=0)
test   = pd.read_csv('Z:\ADwork2\python\PM/test.csv', index_col=0)
sample = pd.read_csv('Z:\ADwork2\python\PM/sample_submission.csv')
 """
# Read in the csv data using pandas 
train  = pd.read_csv('train.csv',index_col=0)
test   = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
sample = pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv')


train.dtypes.value_counts()

train.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).nunique()

features_to_drop = train.nunique()
features_to_drop = features_to_drop.loc[features_to_drop.values==1].index
# now drop these columns from both the training and the test datasets
train = train.drop(features_to_drop,axis=1)
test  = test.drop(features_to_drop,axis=1)

train.isnull().values.any()


X = train.iloc[:,:-1]
y = train['TARGET']

y.value_counts().to_frame().T


from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
X_resampled, y_resampled = SMOTE().fit_resample(X, y)


y_resampled.value_counts().to_frame().T

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, 
                                                  train_size=0.5,
                                                  test_size=0.2, 
                                                  random_state=42, 
                                                  shuffle=True)


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler  = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val   = scaler.transform(X_val)
test    = scaler.transform(test)


model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Dense(units=9, activation="relu", input_shape=(X_train.shape[-1],) ),
        # randomly delete 30% of the input units below
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
        keras.layers.Dense(units=9, activation="relu"),
        # the output layer, with a single neuron
        keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ]
)

# save the initial weights for later
initial_weights = model.get_weights()
model.summary()

#keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

learning_rate = 0.001

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), 
              loss="binary_crossentropy", 
              metrics=keras.metrics.AUC()
             )

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          epochs=500, 
          batch_size=1000, 
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          verbose=0)

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    min_delta = 0.0002, # minimium amount of change to count as an improvement
    patience  = 20,     # how many epochs to wait before stopping
    restore_best_weights=True,
)

model.set_weights(initial_weights)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          epochs=500, 
          batch_size=1000, 
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          verbose=0,
          # add in our early stopping callback
          callbacks=[early_stopping]
        )

sample['TARGET'] = model.predict(test)

sample.to_csv('submission.csv',index=False)
#tf.keras.models.save_model()
model.save('modelcentral.h5')
```

I am saving this model and then loading this model into new python file in the target model

```
from pyexpat import model
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
import numpy  as np
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

import tryt
# Read in the csv data using pandas 
train  = pd.read_csv('train.csv',index_col=0)
test   = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
sample = pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv')


train.dtypes.value_counts()

train.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).nunique()

features_to_drop = train.nunique()
features_to_drop = features_to_drop.loc[features_to_drop.values==1].index
# now drop these columns from both the training and the test datasets
train = train.drop(features_to_drop,axis=1)
test  = test.drop(features_to_drop,axis=1)

train.isnull().values.any()


X = train.iloc[:,:-1]
y = train['TARGET']

y.value_counts().to_frame().T


from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
X_resampled, y_resampled = SMOTE().fit_resample(X, y)


y_resampled.value_counts().to_frame().T

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, 
                                                  train_size=0.5,
                                                  test_size=0.2, 
                                                  random_state=42, 
                                                  shuffle=True)


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler  = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val   = scaler.transform(X_val)
test    = scaler.transform(test)

#f.keras.models.load_model()
# It can be used to reconstruct the model identically.
model = keras.models.load_model("modelcentral.h5")
model.trainable=False
#layer1.trainable = False

#inputs = keras.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
learning_rate = 0.001
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), 
              loss="binary_crossentropy", 
              metrics=keras.metrics.AUC()
             )

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          epochs=500, 
          batch_size=1000, 
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          verbose=0)
model.summary()
```

for now I am just freezing all model layers but what if I need to fine tune last layers for example I HAVE BINARY Classification in source model and what if in the target model there is multi-classification. how can I fine tune last layers? i am following this repo https://github.com/rasbt/stat453-deep-learning-ss21/blob/main/L14/5-transfer-learning-vgg16_small.ipynb to learn fine-tuning of final layers for transfer learning but this code is in pytorch and on image data .. so I am confused

```
model.classifier[1].requires_grad = True
model.classifier[3].requires_grad = True
#For the last layer, because the number of class labels differs compared to ImageNet, we replace the output layer with your own output layer:

model.classifier[6] = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 10)
```

please help and if there is any mistake in current code then guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your source model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=9, activation="relu", input_shape=(10,) ),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=9, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ])

model.save('model.h5')
```

You can do something like this to replace your last layer with some other layer:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")

transfer_model = tf.keras.Sequential()

for idx, l in enumerate(model.layers):
    if idx == len(model.layers) - 1:
      transfer_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation="softmax")) # add output layer with 10 different classes
    else: transfer_model.add(l)
    
print(transfer_model.summary())
```

You can decide which layers you then want to freeze or make trainable using `l.trainable = True / False`. You could also do this all without the for loop if you prefer:

```
model.layers[0].trainable = True
model.layers[2].trainable = True

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation="softmax")(model.layers[-2].output)
transfer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=outputs)
```

Comment: for source model  the last layer would be like this if the target class is binary tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")

Comment: Yes exactly! @user12 does that make sense ?

Comment: and for transfer learning the target model if we have miltil classification suppose 10 classes the last layer would be this outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation="softmax")(model.layers[-2].output) ?? and what is model.layers[-2].output)?

Comment: model.layers[-2].output is just getting the output tensor of the second last layer of your source model

Comment: Thanks alot ...so in my case , binary class in source and multiclass in target .. do I need to fine tune other layers except the last which is used to specify the output class??

Comment: Well that’s all up to you